# analyze entanglement of a multipartite state via its reduced two-qubit states

Tags: entanglement, resource-request

I want resources about entanglement of multipartite states where the author analyzes entanglement of all possible reduced two-qubit states for that.

for example suppose the below state

$$|w\rangle = a|100\rangle + b|010\rangle + c|001\rangle$$

then one analyze entanglement of reduced states qubits (1,2), (1,3) and (2,3)